# Как добавить виджет карты 2gis в React

Tags: reactjs, 2gis-api

Необходимо в React проект добавить виджет 2gis карты, вот на этом сайте формируется виджет.

https://firmsonmap.api.2gis.ru/firmsconstructor/project/69

Добавить нужно в определенный блок и динамически то есть скрипт подгружается с сервера.

```
    componentDidMount() {
    const bitForm = document.getElementById(scriptData);
    if(bitForm){
        const divFragment =  document.createRange().createContextualFragment(sgy);
        bitForm.appendChild(divFragment)
    }
}
```

Вот сам скрипт:

```
<a class="dg-widget-link" href="http://2gis.ru/abakan/firm/70000001044559156/center/91.67322635650636,53.69457211244643/zoom/16?utm_medium=widget-source&utm_campaign=firmsonmap&utm_source=bigMap">Посмотреть на карте Абакана</a><div class="dg-widget-link"><a href="http://2gis.ru/abakan/firm/70000001044559156/photos/70000001044559156/center/91.67322635650636,53.69457211244643/zoom/17?utm_medium=widget-source&utm_campaign=firmsonmap&utm_source=photos">Фотографии компании</a></div><div class="dg-widget-link"><a href="http://2gis.ru/abakan/center/91.673217,53.693893/zoom/16/routeTab/rsType/bus/to/91.673217,53.693893╎Золотой дракон, магазин товаров из Китая?utm_medium=widget-source&utm_campaign=firmsonmap&utm_source=route">Найти проезд до Золотой дракон, магазин товаров из Китая</a></div><script charset="utf-8" src="https://widgets.2gis.com/js/DGWidgetLoader.js"></script><script charset="utf-8">new DGWidgetLoader({"width":640,"height":600,"borderColor":"#a3a3a3","pos":{"lat":53.69457211244643,"lon":91.67322635650636,"zoom":16},"opt":{"city":"abakan"},"org":[{"id":"70000001044559156"}]});</script><noscript style="color:#c00;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;">Виджет карты использует JavaScript. Включите его в настройках вашего браузера.</noscript>
```

При загрузке скрипта изначально выдает ошибку **WidgetLoader is not defined**

Если же статично в index.html подключу

```
<script src="https://widgets.2gis.com/js/DGWidgetLoader.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

то ошибок нет, и даже появляется карта, но она удаляет все мои компоненты и на сайте остается только iframe
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как в React проект добавить виджет карты 2gis, чтобы она встала в определенный блок и остальные компоненты не удалялись?